# Qual é a finalidade do construtor de uma enum?

Tags: java, enums

Em Java construtores são necessários para criar um objeto na memória, ou seja, para instanciar a classe que foi definida. Entretanto, eu descobri que uma **enum** possui um construtor, porem ele não é uma classe, e eu pensava que apenas as classes possuíam construtores.

Veja esta **enum** como exemplo:

```
public enum Genero
{
    MASCULINO(1), FEMININO(2);
    public int codigo;

    private Genero(int codigo)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }        
}
```

Nota:

> Considere que a **enum** esta dentro de uma classe que representa uma
>   pessoa, classe `Pessoa`.

Veja que para usar a **enum** a classe não precisa ser instanciada, exemplo:

```
Pessoa.Genero.FEMININO
```

Gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade do construtor de uma **enum** e se a **enum** tem as mesmas propriedades de uma classe?

Comment: Curiosidade: apesar de conceitualmente o Enum não ser mesmo uma classe (o construtor não pode ser público e não é você que cria instâncias dele, por exemplo), ele tem diversas características de uma classe regular, podendo ter atributos, comportamentos e inclusive membros estáticos. De fato, olhando o bytecode gerado (o código java compilado, por assim dizer), podemos notar que Enums geram o mesmo o código que uma classe depois de compilados.

Comment: @Caffé A sim, é o a mesma coisa que uma classe, porem muda o conceito certo. Você poderia publicar uma resposta explicando?

Comment: Isso, o conceito é diferente: enquanto uma classe pode ter toda sorte de funções, **a função do Enum deveria ser estritamente a de representar uma lista fixa de valores constantes** (é claro que lista e valores podem mudar entre compilações - mas em tempo de execução ela é fixa). Dada a flexibilidade do Enum no Java, já vi programador implementando até regras de negócio complexas dentro do Enum - isso pode trazer algumas dificuldades conforme o sistema cresce. Minha resposta fica dispensada dada a excelente resposta já postada pelo @utluiz ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Construtores em Enums tem exatamente a mesma finalidade de construtores em classes, inicializar valores. Enums não são nada mais do que um tipo específico de classe.

## Enums são classes

A primeira coisa para entender definitivamente Enums é que eles não são nada mais do que classes com algumas características específicas e "açúcar sintático".

Vejamos, a pergunta tem o seguinte exemplo de Enum:

```
public enum Genero
{
    MASCULINO(1), FEMININO(2);
    public int codigo;

    private Genero(int codigo)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

Poderíamos facilmente reescrever o exemplo acima como uma classe normal:

```
public class EnumGenero {
    public static final EnumGenero MASCULINO = new EnumGenero(1), FEMININO = new EnumGenero(2);
    public int codigo;

    private EnumGenero(int codigo)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

E o uso fica *praticamente* igual:

```
EnumGenero masculino1 = EnumGenero.MASCULINO;
Genero masculino2 = Genero.MASCULINO;
```

Pontos importantes:

1. Constantes de Enums não são nada mais do que atributos estáticos. Veja no exemplo como eu instancio a classe nas constantes. É a mesma coisa com o Enum, a diferença é que você não precisa colocar os modificadores de acesso nem o `new`, mas o comportamento é exatamente o mesmo.
2. Enums são instanciados exatamente como classes. Como disse no item anterior, a diferença é que o `new` fica implícito na sintaxe simplificada do Enum.
3. O construtor do Enum é sempre `private` e você não precisa colocar esse modificador, é redundante. No caso da classe, depende de você colocar ali para evitar que outras instâncias sejam criadas.

## Enums vs. Classes

Existe alguma diferença entre usar Enums e classes como a que coloquei acima? Vamos considerar as diferenças para o exemplo cima.

Sobre o Enum:

- Pode usar com `switch` e algumas IDEs avisam caso você esqueça de colocar algum valor.
- Sintaxe simplificada que dá certas garantias, tais como que não haverá outras instâncias além das constantes pré-definidas.
- Métodos auxiliares como `name()`, `ordinal()`, `valueOf()` e `values()`.

Sobre a classe:

- Mais flexibilidade, permite herança e outras construções, embora isso geralmente não seja recomendado a não ser que haja uma razão muito forte.
- Desvantagem de você ter que adicionar manualmente todos os modificadores de acesso, além da instanciação de cada constante.
- Não tem os métodos auxiliares do Enum por padrão, mas podem ser implementados, embora não de forma muito simples e segura.

## Observações sobre a implementação do Enum

### Encapsulamento

O seu Enum pode ter o atributo `codigo` acessado via `getter`:

```
public enum Genero {
    MASCULINO(1), FEMININO(2);
    private int codigo;

    private Genero(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }      
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }  
}
```

Existe alguma necessidade disso? Tecnicamente não.

Embora geralmente seja desejável encapsular os atributos para não permitir o acesso direto via código externo, este argumento não é tão forte quando falamos de constantes.

O valor não muda e não há um motivo forte neste caso específico para encapsular um atributo que tem baixíssima probabilidade de mudar no futuro.

Entretanto, as razões mais fortes para usar um `getter` é para manter consistência (é ruim trabalhar num sistema onde ora os atributos são expostos, ora não são) e para possibilitar refatoração interna no futuro, mesmo que isso não seja visível agora.

Uma situação onde eu **não** recomenda usar encapsulamento é em classes internas onde o uso do valor é privado. Exemplo:

```
public class ProcessaAlgoComGenero {
    public enum Genero {
        MASCULINO(1), FEMININO(2);
        private int codigo;
        Genero(int codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }
    }
    public void processaGenero(Genero g) {
        System.out.println(g.codigo);
    }
}
```

E a chamada fica assim:

```
new ProcessaAlgoComGenero().processaGenero(ProcessaAlgoComGenero.Genero.MASCULINO);
```

Perceba que o atributo `codigo` somente é acessível dentro da classe `ProcessaAlgoComGenero`. Encapsular um atributo usado apenas internamente é desnecessário.

## Recuperando valores pelo código

É algo comum quando adicionamos atributos aos valores do Enum precisarmos recuperar as constantes com base nesse valor.

Enquanto para recuperar a constante com base no nome usando o método pronto `valueOf()`, temos que construir o outro método nós mesmos.

Então, se em algum momento você precisar recuperar o Enum pelo `codigo`, pode fazer isso:

```
public static Genero ofCode(int codigo) {
    for (Genero g : values()) {
        if (g.codigo == codigo) {
            return g;
        }
    }
    return null; //ou lança uma exceção
}
```

Note que o método `ofCode` percorre todos os valores do Enum através do array retornado por `values()` e procura pela constante com o `codigo` a ser recuperado.

A vantagem desse código ao invés de um `if` ou `switch` é que você pode reaproveitá-lo para qualquer situação, inclusive outros Enums, com um mínimo de alteração.

Você poderia fazer simplesmente assim:

```
public static Genero ofCode(int codigo) {
    if (MASCULINO.codigo == codigo) return MASCULINO;
    if (FEMININO.codigo == codigo) return FEMININO;
    return null; //ou lança uma exceção
}
```

Mas nesse caso para cada enum você teria que reescrever tudo.

Se houver muitas constantes e o tempo de execução for uma preocupação, você pode usar um mapa para tornar o tempo de procura constante.

Primeiro você precisaria inicializar o mapa logo que o Enum for inicializado. Basta adicionar isso no Enum:

```
static Map<Integer, Genero> cache = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (Genero g : values()) {
        cache.put(g.codigo, g);
    }
}
```

E depois o método `ofCode` é trivial e eficiente:

```
public static Genero ofCode(int codigo) {
    return cache.get(codigo);
}
```

## Considerações

Usar Enum é bom, facilita a codificação e faz com que o código fique mais seguro contra equívocos e mesmo contra programadores "espertinhos".

Enums são flexíveis como classes, embora com várias outras restrições. Como visto no exemplo acima, é possível criar construções complexas dentro de Enums. Porém, use isso somente em casos onde realmente for necessário, caos contrário você está adicionando complexidade e dores de cabeça desnecessárias ao seu programa.

Answer (score 12):

Construtores de enums em java são usados em situações onde você quer adicionar mais informações aos valores do enum além do seu nome. No seu exemplo, a sua enum tem associada aos valores MASCULINO e FEMININO os códigos 1 e 2 (*), respectivamente. A vantagem disso é que você pode continuar usando os nomes que fazem sentido (MASCULINO, FEMININO), mas quando for armazenar os valores (por exemplo, num banco de dados) você armazenaria o valor associado a eles (novamente, nesse caso, assumindo que o seu esquema do BD use 1 para homens e 2 para mulheres).

Outras vantagens de associar mais dados aos valores da enum é a possibilidade de você adicionar uma lógica na enum mesma. Um exemplo que eu já vi é [de um SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceFeatures.java), onde cada valor da enum tem um código (string), e uma função extra na enum é usada para concatenar todos os valores a partir de um `EnumSet`.

(*) - Declarar o campo que armazena o valor agregado como `public` não é apropriado, pois um código mal-escrito pode alterá-lo e o seu programa pode começar a ter erros difíceis de serem identificados.

Comment: O campo código deve ser private neste caso?

Comment: Sim, privado, com um método get para acessá-lo, algo como `public int getCodigo() { return this.codigo; }`

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Outra opção é declarar como *final*, assim: `public final int codigo;`, assim ele também não poderá ser modificado depois de ter seu valor atribuído no construtor do enum. Eu uso bastante o *final* nestas situações e em outras estruturas de dados para evitar a verborragia do "get".

Answer (score 6):

Funciona de forma similar, mas você não pode chamar o construtor você mesmo.

No exemplo que você colocou, o construtor é chamado duas vezes e `MASCULINO` e `FEMININO` são inicializados com o valor passado (1 e 2 respectivamente).

A principal diferença desse enum para uma classe, é que no enum, todos os objetos declarados no início são iniciados automaticamente e mais nenhum depois disso.

Comment: Neste casso para usar a enum eu devo fazer isso: `Pessoa.Genero.FEMININO` a classe não é instanciada para utiliza-lo.

Comment: Na verdade, acho o exemplo ruim. Nesse caso seria melhor não usar o construtor, para poder acessar como você comentou.

Da forma como passou, usando construtor, o ideal é fazer um método para pegar os valores que quiser e só deveria usar se o enum for mais complexo que isso.

Comment: Sim, mais ainda não consigo entender a finalidade do construtor já que não é possível fazer `Pessoa.Genero genero = new Pessoa.Genero(2)`, o construtor seria realmente necessário na enum?

Comment: Seria útil se o enum fosse algo mais complexo. Se no lugar de Gênero, fosse um enum de personas. Você poderia ter definido no enum alguns atributos como Gênero, Idade, Profissão, etc.

Comment: Como assim mais complexo?

Comment: Mal, acabei editando enquanto você perguntava.